# Setting UIReturnKeyType in Ionic Cordova App

Tags: ios, cordova, user-interface, ionic-framework

I am in the final steps for my first Ionic-App and I found a small thing I'd like to change. The app needs to be in German and not in English, so I got a challenge to do this for iOS.

The app has a search-function with an search-input-field. On Android there are no problems with the language, on iOS 9 I always got the "Return" Button in the keyboard.... Space is called "Leerzeichen". It looks like Apple did not translate the Button "Return" into German, you can see that [here](http://erike.net/wordpress/?p=255).

All other elements like "Done" are translated. Therefore I set up the Language-Settings in Xcode.

Does anybody have an idea how I can set the `UIReturnKeyType` in Ionic or Cordova? It looks like there is [no solution](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard/issues/54) so far.

Comment: Did you ever find out anything here?

Comment: Not so far, there are different keys for the plist-file, but if apple does not translate we have no chance. On the other side, it should be ok for the user because there always stands "space"